# Questions around Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am reading this doc: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens

1. What is web data vs app data?
2. What is screen view vs page view e.g.

   ```
   ga('send', 'screenview', {'screenName': 'Home'});
   ```

   and

   ```
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web data is data that comes through your website. App data is data that comes through your mobile app.

Screen view and page view are the same things, just called differently depending on whether you are using a mobile app ("screen view") or a web app ("page view").

Answer (score 0):

It is easy - all there - "Screens in Google Analytics represent content users are viewing within an app. The equivalent concept for a website is pages." Screen view - in application, Page view - on web sites. Web data - sites data, app data - data from applications.

Comment: But I thought we are talking about web app? Isn't a web page a screen in app? Is't the web data also the app data?

Comment: @xcoder for analytics mobile web is WEB, and mobile native apps is APPs. Screenviews are only for APPs